# Return from find to editor shortcut in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

I press <kbd>⌘F</kbd> and enter a search term and I see its first occurrence selected in the editor. I would like to return focus to the editor to start editing the occurrence there. Can I do that with a keyboard shortcut, without closing the search like when using <kbd>esc</kbd>?

Comment: To move focus to Editor hit Escape and edit the highlighted term. Later you can iterate between found occurrences using Cmd/Ctrl+F3 shortcut right inside Editor.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, right, it's possible to iterate without search panel opened, unfortunately without highlighted occurrences.

Comment: `unfortunately without highlighted occurrences.` **Highlight usages** (Shift+Cmd+F7 default shortcut) will highlight usages in file.

Comment: @Andrey That actually solves my question! I would love to accept it as an answer if you add it. Thanks again.